# What's the meaning of "theme()"?

Tags: theming, nodes

I am new to drupal, I read some introductory tutorial.

I notice there is some [theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) function in template files.

Like this:

```
<?php print theme('uc_price',array('price'=>$price)); ?>
```

It will generate some html source code:

```
<span class="uc-price" data-thmr="thmr_45">$59.85</span>
```

Is it **theme()** function is only to generate the html source? If this is the case, why I need use **theme()** function? I Think just only write html source manually.

I use Zen base-theme, Does **theme()** is one of zen's native function?

Please tell me the real usage of **"theme()"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding about theme is right. It is for wrapping data with html elements. Advantage is that you can seperate view part and logic part. There are also default theme which you can use out of box

Comment: **theme()** seems only generate ```<span>```, and what's meaning of ```data-thmr="thmr_45"```?

Comment: first attribute "uc_price" is the name of the theme. There are lots of other themes like 'image_style', etc. To call image_style theme you use theme('image_style',array(...))  You can create your own theme as well.   and data-thmr="thmr_45" i dont know what html attribute that is. That is not very important thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This is my understand: **theme()** is a drupal native function, and some modules and base-theme will implement **theme()** function, and add more out of box  method. right?

Comment: You are right. But our discussion here alone wont give much insight to the concept. Continue your effort. my wishes